# Is possible to process a CSS variable?

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

I have my code with a CSS variable, let's call it --element-padding, which allows multiple values like `8px 0 12px 79px`, this variable is in a webcomponent that I own, and it's being used by third parties.

And I use it in my webcomponent CSS

```css
padding: var(--element-padding, '0');
```

This variable allows my users to override the padding declaring it when styling my component

```css
.awesome-component {
   --element-padding: 8px 0 12px 79px;
}
```

Now I have found that I would need to process it, because I just need the padding-top for another style.

One option would be to change --element-padding to 4 different variables

```
--element-padding-top
--element-padding-right
--element-padding-bottom
--element-padding-left
```

But then, the users will have to change their code to adapt to the new variables, causing a lot of trouble.

Is there any way to get this variable and make some kind of splitting-calculations before using it in the var() CSS function? that way I can get the 1st position of the variable, without the need to tell the users to change their implementation.

(The code and explanation is a simplified one which doesn't adjust to the real case, but the point is about splitting a variable containing 4 measures into 4 different variables, without the need to add/modify variables in the user side / root)

Comment: How is JS involved in the question?

Comment: Maybe there could be some JS option to solve my problem, it's doesn't need to be pure CSS

Comment: Given your latest update, It seems that the question is an over-simplification and doesn't really represent what you're trying to do. This will make it difficult to appreciate the nuances and provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: That being said, I think I know what you mean - see updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Original answer at the bottom**

I think I understand that you want to allow your consumers to continue using the `--element-padding` CSS variable and you want to derive the individual top/right/bottom/left values from that they can customise the `--element-padding` but you're going to be using the individual properties in your development going forward.

You can read CSS variables:

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--element-padding')
```

And set them:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--element-padding-top', '8px')
```

Putting it all together:

```js
const updatePadding = () => {

  let elementPadding = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--element-padding'); // "8px 0 12px 79px";

  let [top, right, bottom, left] = elementPadding.trim().split(/\s+/);

  const docStyle = document.documentElement.style;
  docStyle.setProperty('--element-padding-top', top);
  docStyle.setProperty('--element-padding-right', right);
  docStyle.setProperty('--element-padding-bottom', bottom);
  docStyle.setProperty('--element-padding-left', left);

};

updatePadding();
```

```css
:root {
  --element-padding: 8px 0 12px 79px;
  /* Default values but will overridden by updatePadding() */
  --element-padding-top: 8px;
  --element-padding-right: 0;
  --element-padding-bottom: 12px;
  --element-padding-left: 79px;
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You should think about the other way around. Rather than split `--element-padding` why not declare the individual variables and then use those to create the all-in-one CSS variable.

```
::root {
  --element-padding-top: 8px;
  --element-padding-right: 0;
  --element-padding-bottom: 12px;
  --element-padding-left: 79px;
  --element-padding: var(--element-padding-top) var(--element-padding-right) var(--element-padding-bottom) var(--element-padding-left);
}
```

You can still use the original variable as you previously did.

```
  padding: var(--element-padding, '0');
```

Comment: That's what I said, but I don't want to change the variable, because it will cause a breaking change in the interface of the users of my component

Comment: Why would it break it, you still have the original `--element-padding` variable, plus the 4 new ones? Could you update your question with an example of how this would break things?

Comment: This would break because I am maintaining the part of a webcomponent, that has the variable implementation, and all my consumers are using the webcomponent, setting the --element-padding to their needs to override my styles.

If I change the variables, the paddings will not be correct for the users until they refactor their code

Comment: Could you add that extra information to the question so that we may know exactly what you need?

Comment: Their overrides should still override your declaration though!

Comment: Updated with the breaking explanation

Comment: Updated answer with JS manipulation of CSS variables.

Answer (score 1):

A key thing to note here is that *CSS Custom Properties* may reference other *CSS Custom Properties*:

**Example:**

```
:root {
  --element-padding-top: 8px;
  --element-padding: var(--element-padding-top) 0 12px 79px;
}

 .element1 {
   padding: var(--element-padding, '0');
 }

 .element2 {
   padding-top: var(--element-padding-top);
 }
```

Comment: I have edited the question, I don't want to add more variables or modify the existing ones in the root side :( but thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use default values. If the ones who use your component haven't set the values, no biggie, but you give them the opportunity to declare them if they want to.

```
:host {
  --element-padding: 20px;

  padding:
     var(--element-padding-top,    var(--element-padding))
     var(--element-padding-right,  var(--element-padding))
     var(--element-padding-bottom, var(--element-padding))
     var(--element-padding-left,   var(--element-padding));
}
```

The downside is that they probably can't declare padding as a set of numbers.

Comment: Exactly, the default value wouldn't be correct because it's a set of numbers :(

Comment: @Víctor I guess the only thing you can do is to use the ready method and check how `element-padding` is declared, and set the rest of the four variables based on that. Clumsy, IMHO, but sadly true. Using [mixin](https://medium.com/@adrjohnston/native-css-mixins-ee2a50e07b54), or just declare padding-top et al  with empty variable names. Then the browser will fall back on the default `padding` declaration.